# Find matching properties in array of objects (angular5)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, match

I have an array with objects. I want to know if certain properties of the object match and save the matches in a new array.

Example:

```
[{id: 1, firstname: 'Bob', Lastname: 'Lupo'}, {id: 2, firstname: 'Tessa', Lastname: 'Moon'},
{id: 3, firstname: 'Erik' , Lastname: 'Deurne'}, {id: 4, firstname: 'Bob', Lastname: 'Lupo'}, {id: 5, firstname: 'Bob' , Lastname: 'Lupo'}]
```

I want to know if the 2 propertjes of the object firstname and lastname match with the properties in an other object then I want to put the id`s that match in a new array.

So i this case it would be [[1,4,5]]

Does someone know a way to do this?

Thx

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: @GibboK a loop in a loop that can work but its not a clean way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```js
var array = [{id: 1, firstname: 'Bob', Lastname: 'Lupo'}, {id: 2, firstname: 'Tessa', Lastname: 'Moon'},
{id: 3, firstname: 'Erik' , Lastname: 'Deurne'}, {id: 4, firstname: 'Bob', Lastname: 'Lupo'}, {id: 5, firstname: 'Bob' , Lastname: 'Lupo'}]

let duplicates = {}

array.map(item => {
    let key=item.firstname+'_'+item.Lastname
    if( !duplicates[ key ]){
        duplicates[ key ] = []
    }
    duplicates[ key ].push(item.id)
},{})

duplicateNamesIds = []
Object.values( duplicates ).forEach( value => {
    if( value.length > 1 ){
        duplicateNamesIds.push( value )
    }
})
console.log(duplicateNamesIds)
```

Comment: great peace of code onl;y value.length gives error and why do we need this the value already has the matching id`s?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{
        id: 1,
        firstname: 'Bob',
        Lastname: 'Lupo'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        firstname: 'Tessa',
        Lastname: 'Moon'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        firstname: 'Erik',
        Lastname: 'Deurne'
    }, {
        id: 4,
        firstname: 'Bob',
        Lastname: 'Lupo'
    }, {
        id: 5,
        firstname: 'Bob',
        Lastname: 'Lupo'
    }
];

var result = data.reduce((obj, val) => {
    obj[val.firstname + "_" + val.Lastname] = obj[val.firstname + "_" + val.Lastname] || [];
    obj[val.firstname + "_" + val.Lastname].push(val.id);
    return obj;
}, {});

result = Object.values(result).filter(val=>val.length>1);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This, however, asserts that neither `firstname` nor `Lastname` contain a `_`. You never know ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 is to make a tree of all `firstname-lastname` combinations and their ids. We can do this in a single `reduce` on the data. (note: if you can come up with a hash function for your objects that is safe to use, you do not need 2 levels in this tree)

```
[ { id, firstname, lastname } ] -> { firstname: { lastname: [ id ] } }
```

```js
console.log(
  getData().reduce(
    (tree, person) => {
      if (!tree[person.firstname])
        tree[person.firstname] = {};
      if (!tree[person.firstname][person.Lastname]) 
        tree[person.firstname][person.Lastname] = [];


      tree[person.firstname][person.Lastname].push(person.id);
      return tree;
    }, {}
  )
);


function getData() { return [{id: 1, firstname: 'Bob', Lastname: 'Lupo'}, {id: 2, firstname: 'Tessa', Lastname: 'Moon'},
{id: 3, firstname: 'Erik' , Lastname: 'Deurne'}, {id: 4, firstname: 'Bob', Lastname: 'Lupo'}, {id: 5, firstname: 'Bob' , Lastname: 'Lupo'}] };
```

Once we have this tree, we can go to step 2. We flatten the tree to just the sets of ids. Then, we filter out all the id sets that contain only one id using `filter`:

```
{ firstname: { lastname: [ id ] } } -> [ [ id ] ]
```

```js
const flattenTree = tree => Object.entries(tree)
  .reduce(
    (acc, [k, v]) => Object.entries(v).reduce(
        (acc, [k, v]) => acc.concat([v]),
        acc
      ),
    []
  );
  
const duplicates = xxs => xxs.filter(xs => xs.length > 1);

console.log(
  duplicates(
    flattenTree(getTree())
  )
);



function getTree() {
  return getData().reduce(
    (tree, person) => {
      if (!tree[person.firstname])
        tree[person.firstname] = {};
      if (!tree[person.firstname][person.Lastname]) 
        tree[person.firstname][person.Lastname] = [];


      tree[person.firstname][person.Lastname].push(person.id);
      return tree;
    }, {}
  )
};

function getData() { return [{id: 1, firstname: 'Bob', Lastname: 'Lupo'}, {id: 2, firstname: 'Tessa', Lastname: 'Moon'},
{id: 3, firstname: 'Erik' , Lastname: 'Deurne'}, {id: 4, firstname: 'Bob', Lastname: 'Lupo'}, {id: 5, firstname: 'Bob' , Lastname: 'Lupo'}] };
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```js
const data = [
  {id: 1, firstname: 'Bob', Lastname: 'Lupo'}, 
  {id: 2, firstname: 'Tessa', Lastname: 'Moon'},
  {id: 3, firstname: 'Erik' , Lastname: 'Deurne'}, 
  {id: 4, firstname: 'Bob', Lastname: 'Lupo'}, 
  {id: 5, firstname: 'Bob' , Lastname: 'Lupo'}
]

// Definitely not the most beautiful code I've ever written
let result = Object.values(
  data.reduce((a, c) => {
    a[c.firstname] = a[c.firstname] || {};
    a[c.firstname][c.Lastname] = [...(a[c.firstname][c.Lastname] || []), c.id];
    return a;
  }, []))
  .map(o => [].concat(...Object.values(o)))
  .filter(arr => arr.length > 1); 

console.log(result);
```